# react-native navigation false route params in navigation listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using react native navigation and have two tabs. One of them has a list of entites, the other has a form to submit entities. When ever a new entity is submitted, I'd like to refresh the first tab to be sure, the newest data gets loaded.

I navigate to the first tab like this:

`navigation?.navigate('Main', {refresh: true});`

This props gets saved as follows:

`let {refresh} = route.params;`

To check, if the screen needs to refresh, I added a listener in useEffect() like this:

```
    useEffect(() => {

        const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () =>{

            if(refresh){
                doRefresh()
            }

        })

    }, [])
```

Unfortunately, neither "refresh" nor "route.params" directly is ever true inside the listener. Passing the param works, because I took a closer look at the var and it gets true, whenever I submit.

Do I need to access the route.params inside a navigation listener in another way?

Thanks and hit me up, if you need more information on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `useEffect` only runs once as your dependencies array `[]` is empty, and therefore your listener only receives the initial value of `refresh`.
You need to pass `refresh` as a dependency to `useEffect`, and I don't think you even need the `focus` listener in your case so you would end up with this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (refresh) {
    doRefresh()
  }
}, [refresh])
```

Comment: Thanks that did it!

Answer (score 1):

```
const onPressCountry = (item,index) => {
    navigation.push('SignUp2', {selectedCountryId:item?.countryID, selectedCountryName: item?.name} )
}
```

use **navigation.push** instead of **navigation.navigate**